# My JavaScript is Not working Correctly or is not connecting

Tags: javascript, html, css, histogram, chat

I am trying to make an Intrest calculator with histogram plotted I have found the scripts online as I am new to javaScript.
So the output I want is like this [Desired Outpyt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DZdc.png)
and the output I am getting is this [comming output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiPIN.png)
So I really need some help
One, the blue buttons with + and - signs are crazy out.
secondly, the histogram is not showing.

So please help me with this I will grateful.

I have copy-pasted the code from this site

https://codingdiksha.com/build-a-compound-interest-calculator-using-chart-js-in-html5-css3-and-javascript/

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css" >
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Savings Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="initial_deposit">Initial Deposit</label>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-group col-md-6 col-sm-8">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="sub" data-field="initial_deposit">−</button>
</div>
<input class="form-control text-center" id="initial_deposit" type="text" name="initial_deposit" min="100" max="1000000" step="100" value="$5000" data-value="5000" data-prepend="$">
<div class="input-group-append">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="add" data-field="initial_deposit">+</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="contribution_amount">Contributions</label>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-group col-md-6 col-sm-8">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="sub" data-field="contribution_amount">−</button>
</div>
<input class="form-control text-center" id="contribution_amount" type="text" name="contribution_amount" min="0" max="10000" step="50" value="$100" data-value="100" data-prepend="$">
<div class="input-group-append">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="add" data-field="contribution_amount">+</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
<input class="form-check-input" id="contribution_period_monthly" type="radio" name="contribution_period" value="12" checked>
<label class="form-check-label" for="contribution_period_monthly">monthly</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
<input class="form-check-input" id="contribution_period_annually" type="radio" name="contribution_period" value="1">
<label class="form-check-label" for="contribution_period_annually">annually</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="investment_timespan">Investment Time Span</label>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
<input class="form-control" id="investment_timespan" type="range" name="investment_timespan" min="2" max="50" step="1" value="5">
</div>
</div>
<span id="investment_timespan_text">5 years</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="estimated_return">Estimated Rate of Return</label>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-group col-md-6 col-sm-8">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="sub" data-field="estimated_return">−</button>
</div>
<input class="form-control text-center" id="estimated_return" type="text" name="estimated_return" min="0" max="50" step="0.25" value="5.00%" data-value="5.00" data-append="%">
<div class="input-group-append">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="add" data-field="estimated_return">+</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div>Compound Frequency</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
<input class="form-check-input" id="compound_period_daily" type="radio" name="compound_period" value="365">
<label class="form-check-label" for="compound_period_daily">daily</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
<input class="form-check-input" id="compound_period_monthly" type="radio" name="compound_period" value="12" checked>
<label class="form-check-label" for="compound_period_monthly">monthly</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
<input class="form-check-input" id="compound_period_annually" type="radio" name="compound_period" value="1">
<label class="form-check-label" for="compound_period_annually">annually</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 text-center">
<div>Future Balance</div>
<div class="h3" id="future_balance">?</div>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js">    </script>
</html>
```

Script.js

```
(function () {
var initial_deposit = document.querySelector('#initial_deposit'),
contribution_amount = document.querySelector('#contribution_amount'),
investment_timespan = document.querySelector('#investment_timespan'),
investment_timespan_text = document.querySelector('#investment_timespan_text'),
estimated_return = document.querySelector('#estimated_return'),
future_balance = document.querySelector('#future_balance');
function updateValue(element, action) {
var min = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('min')),
max = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('max')),
step = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('step')) || 1,
oldValue = element.dataset.value || element.defaultValue || 0,
newValue = parseFloat(element.value.replace(/\$/, ''));
if (isNaN(parseFloat(newValue))) {
newValue = oldValue;
} else {
if (action == 'add') {
newValue += step;
} else if (action == 'sub') {
newValue -= step;
}       
newValue = newValue < min ? min : newValue > max ? max : newValue;
}
element.dataset.value = newValue;
element.value = (element.dataset.prepend || '') + newValue + (element.dataset.append || '');
updateChart();
}
function getChartData() {
var P = parseFloat(initial_deposit.dataset.value), // Principal
r = parseFloat(estimated_return.dataset.value / 100), // Annual Interest Rate
c = parseFloat(contribution_amount.dataset.value), // Contribution Amount
n = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="compound_period"]:checked').value), // Compound Period
n2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="contribution_period"]:checked').value), // Contribution Period
t = parseInt(investment_timespan.value), // Investment Time Span
currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear()
;
var labels = [];
for (var year = currentYear; year < currentYear + t; year++) {
labels.push(year);
}
var principal_dataset = {
label: 'Total Principal',
backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 123, 255)',
data: []
};
var interest_dataset = {
label: "Total Interest",
backgroundColor: 'rgb(23, 162, 184)',
data: []
};
for (var i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
var principal = P + ( c * n2 * i ),
interest = 0,
balance = principal;
if (r) {
var x = Math.pow(1 + r / n, n * i),
compound_interest = P * x,
contribution_interest = c * (x - 1) / (r / n2);
interest = (compound_interest + contribution_interest - principal).toFixed(0)
balance = (compound_interest + contribution_interest).toFixed(0);
}
future_balance.innerHTML = '$' + balance;
principal_dataset.data.push(principal);
interest_dataset.data.push(interest);
}
return {
labels: labels,
datasets: [principal_dataset, interest_dataset]
}
}
function updateChart() {
var data = getChartData();
chart.data.labels = data.labels;
chart.data.datasets[0].data = data.datasets[0].data;
chart.data.datasets[1].data = data.datasets[1].data;
chart.update();
}
initial_deposit.addEventListener('change', function () {
updateValue(this);
});
contribution_amount.addEventListener('change', function () {
updateValue(this);
});
estimated_return.addEventListener('change', function () {
updateValue(this);
});
investment_timespan.addEventListener('change', function () {
investment_timespan_text.innerHTML = this.value + ' years';
updateChart();
});
investment_timespan.addEventListener('input', function () {
investment_timespan_text.innerHTML = this.value + ' years';
});
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[name="contribution_period"], [name="compound_period"]');
for (var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
radios[j].addEventListener('change', updateChart);
}
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-counter]');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
var button = buttons[i];
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
var field = document.querySelector('[name="' + this.dataset.field + '"]'),
action = this.dataset.counter;
if (field) {
updateValue(field, action);
}
});
}
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'),
chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: getChartData(),
options: {
legend: {
display: false
},
tooltips: {
mode: 'index',
intersect: false,
callbacks: {
label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': $' + tooltipItem.yLabel;
}
}
},
responsive: true,
scales: {
xAxes: [{
stacked: true,
scaleLabel: {
display: true,
labelString: 'Year'
}
}],
yAxes: [{
stacked: true,
ticks: {
callback: function (value) {
return '$' + value;
}
},
scaleLabel: {
display: true,
labelString: 'Balance'
}
}]
}
}
});
})();
```

Comment: Please also copy-paste your code into a code block on your post.

Comment: You need to include the Bootstrap CDN. Add this to your head: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />` and it'll do magic, I promise.

Comment: Yeah it did the work for designing but Histogram is still not showing

Comment: I was copy-pasting the code it was giving some error so i just gave the source from where i took it

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: i don't know it just don't get the histogram

Comment: wait i will try to send my code

Comment: @AhteshamKhan Because the code given by the example is incomplete and has errors, you will get this output. I have adjusted the example and submitted it as an answer, which should help you

Comment: Here i have attached the files *Code now please tell me where am i wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do four things

---

1. Add `bootstrap.min.css`

---

2. Replace

   `future_balance.innerHTML = ' + balance;`

   with

   `future_balance.innerHTML = '' + balance;`

   on line 74

---

3. Replace

   `return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': + tooltipItem.yLabel;`

   with

   `return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ':' + tooltipItem.yLabel;`

   on line 148

---

4. Replace

   `return ' + value;`

   with

   `return '' + value;`

   on line 166

```js
(function() {
  var initial_deposit = document.querySelector('#initial_deposit'),
    contribution_amount = document.querySelector('#contribution_amount'),
    investment_timespan = document.querySelector('#investment_timespan'),
    investment_timespan_text = document.querySelector('#investment_timespan_text'),
    estimated_return = document.querySelector('#estimated_return'),
    future_balance = document.querySelector('#future_balance');

  function updateValue(element, action) {
    var min = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('min')),
      max = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('max')),
      step = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('step')) || 1,
      oldValue = element.dataset.value || element.defaultValue || 0,
      newValue = parseFloat(element.value.replace(/$/, ''));

    if (isNaN(parseFloat(newValue))) {
      newValue = oldValue;
    } else {
      if (action == 'add') {
        newValue += step;
      } else if (action == 'sub') {
        newValue -= step;
      }

      newValue = newValue < min ? min : newValue > max ? max : newValue;
    }

    element.dataset.value = newValue;
    element.value = (element.dataset.prepend || '') + newValue + (element.dataset.append || '');

    updateChart();
  }

  function getChartData() {
    var P = parseFloat(initial_deposit.dataset.value), // Principal
      r = parseFloat(estimated_return.dataset.value / 100), // Annual Interest Rate
      c = parseFloat(contribution_amount.dataset.value), // Contribution Amount
      n = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="compound_period"]:checked').value), // Compound Period
      n2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="contribution_period"]:checked').value), // Contribution Period
      t = parseInt(investment_timespan.value), // Investment Time Span
      currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();

    var labels = [];
    for (var year = currentYear; year < currentYear + t; year++) {
      labels.push(year);
    }

    var principal_dataset = {
      label: 'Total Principal',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 123, 255)',
      data: []
    };

    var interest_dataset = {
      label: "Total Interest",
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(23, 162, 184)',
      data: []
    };

    for (var i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
      var principal = P + (c * n2 * i),
        interest = 0,
        balance = principal;

      if (r) {
        var x = Math.pow(1 + r / n, n * i),
          compound_interest = P * x,
          contribution_interest = c * (x - 1) / (r / n2);
        interest = (compound_interest + contribution_interest - principal).toFixed(0)
        balance = (compound_interest + contribution_interest).toFixed(0);
      }

      future_balance.innerHTML = '' + balance;
      principal_dataset.data.push(principal);
      interest_dataset.data.push(interest);
    }

    return {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [principal_dataset, interest_dataset]
    }
  }

  function updateChart() {
    var data = getChartData();

    chart.data.labels = data.labels;
    chart.data.datasets[0].data = data.datasets[0].data;
    chart.data.datasets[1].data = data.datasets[1].data;
    chart.update();
  }

  initial_deposit.addEventListener('change', function() {
    updateValue(this);
  });

  contribution_amount.addEventListener('change', function() {
    updateValue(this);
  });

  estimated_return.addEventListener('change', function() {
    updateValue(this);
  });

  investment_timespan.addEventListener('change', function() {
    investment_timespan_text.innerHTML = this.value + ' years';
    updateChart();
  });

  investment_timespan.addEventListener('input', function() {
    investment_timespan_text.innerHTML = this.value + ' years';
  });

  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[name="contribution_period"], [name="compound_period"]');
  for (var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
    radios[j].addEventListener('change', updateChart);
  }

  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-counter]');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var field = document.querySelector('[name="' + this.dataset.field + '"]'),
        action = this.dataset.counter;

      if (field) {
        updateValue(field, action);
      }
    });
  }

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'),
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: getChartData(),
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: false,
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ':' + tooltipItem.yLabel;
            }
          }
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Year'
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
              callback: function(value) {
                return '' + value;
              }
            },
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Balance'
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });

})();
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="initial_deposit">Initial Deposit</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="sub" data-field="initial_deposit">−</button>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control text-center" id="initial_deposit" type="text" name="initial_deposit" min="100" max="1000000" step="100" value="$5000" data-value="5000" data-prepend="$">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="add" data-field="initial_deposit">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contribution_amount">Contributions</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="sub" data-field="contribution_amount">−</button>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control text-center" id="contribution_amount" type="text" name="contribution_amount" min="0" max="10000" step="50" value="$100" data-value="100" data-prepend="$">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="add" data-field="contribution_amount">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" id="contribution_period_monthly" type="radio" name="contribution_period" value="12" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="contribution_period_monthly">monthly</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" id="contribution_period_annually" type="radio" name="contribution_period" value="1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="contribution_period_annually">annually</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="investment_timespan">Investment Time Span</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" id="investment_timespan" type="range" name="investment_timespan" min="2" max="50" step="1" value="5">
          </div>
        </div>
        <span id="investment_timespan_text">5 years</span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="estimated_return">Estimated Rate of Return</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="sub" data-field="estimated_return">−</button>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control text-center" id="estimated_return" type="text" name="estimated_return" min="0" max="50" step="0.25" value="5.00%" data-value="5.00" data-append="%">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="add" data-field="estimated_return">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div>Compound Frequency</div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" id="compound_period_daily" type="radio" name="compound_period" value="365">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="compound_period_daily">daily</label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" id="compound_period_monthly" type="radio" name="compound_period" value="12" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="compound_period_monthly">monthly</label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" id="compound_period_annually" type="radio" name="compound_period" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="compound_period_annually">annually</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
      <div>Future Balance</div>
      <div class="h3" id="future_balance">?</div>
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: No buddy histogram is still not plotting

Comment: @AhteshamKhan What is the error message? It's definitely possible to draw a histogram, you can press the Run code snippet button in my answer and you'll see it drawn

Comment: I don't know I have copy-pasted all your code but it's still not working i think i am not giving HTML tags correctly

Comment: Can you please share these files somehow? I will be really greatfull.

Comment: @AhteshamKhan The code in the answer is all the code. If you still have problems after copying all of them, it should be caused by other factors, so what is the error message? You have to provide it so that I can help you

Comment: There is no error message that the whole problem. I am getting nothing its runs correctly i open the index.html file but it's not show histogram your code works well it runs correctly in snippet but when I copy-past exact words I don't know what happens it stops working

Comment: @AhteshamKhan By no error do you mean that there is no error popping up on the screen, or is there no error even in DevTools?

Comment: it was no error in anywhere i was just not adding the script it did it and it worked thank you so so so much for your help ♥

Comment: @AhteshamKhan Ok, have a good day

Comment: @AhteshamKhan Can I know why you unaccepted my answer immediately after accepting it? Just curious why you did that

Comment: sorry I didn't know how it happen ! I didn't mean to unaccept your answer . I didn't knew how it happened sorry Ian .

Comment: @ShamKhan That's ok, I thought something happened, I just wanted to know why, now I know it's a misunderstanding

Comment: yeah sorry about that xd

Answer (score 0):

These Things were wrong in your attempt

1. Bootstrap Reference should be a `link` instead of `script`. your code should be

`<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

instead of

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css"></script>
```

2. Make sure your **HTML HIERARCHY** is alright

   > ```
   > <head>
   > <link href="link to file" rel="stylesheet">
   > </head>
   > <body>
   > your code
   > <script src="">
   > </body>
   > ```
3. Your chart is not workig because you have syntax errors in Javascript code.
   there are unclosed `''` at line 74,148,166

> ```
> future_balance.innerHTML = ' + balance; //74
> return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': + tooltipItem.yLabel;//148
> return ' + value;//166
> ```

handle them as

> ```
> future_balance.innerHTML = '' + balance; //74
> return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ':' + tooltipItem.yLabel;//148
> return '' + value;//166
> ```

Here is your working code

If you want to copy paste running code here it is

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="initial_deposit">Initial Deposit</label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-sm-8">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="sub" data-field="initial_deposit">−</button>
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control text-center" id="initial_deposit" type="text" name="initial_deposit" min="100" max="1000000" step="100" value="$5000" data-value="5000" data-prepend="$">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="add" data-field="initial_deposit">+</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contribution_amount">Contributions</label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-sm-8">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="sub" data-field="contribution_amount">−</button>
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control text-center" id="contribution_amount" type="text" name="contribution_amount" min="0" max="10000" step="50" value="$100" data-value="100" data-prepend="$">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="add" data-field="contribution_amount">+</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" id="contribution_period_monthly" type="radio" name="contribution_period" value="12" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="contribution_period_monthly">monthly</label>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" id="contribution_period_annually" type="radio" name="contribution_period" value="1">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="contribution_period_annually">annually</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="investment_timespan">Investment Time Span</label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
                            <input class="form-control" id="investment_timespan" type="range" name="investment_timespan" min="2" max="50" step="1" value="5">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span id="investment_timespan_text">5 years</span>
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="estimated_return">Estimated Rate of Return</label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-sm-8">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="sub" data-field="estimated_return">−</button>
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control text-center" id="estimated_return" type="text" name="estimated_return" min="0" max="50" step="0.25" value="5.00%" data-value="5.00" data-append="%">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-counter="add" data-field="estimated_return">+</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div>Compound Frequency</div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" id="compound_period_daily" type="radio" name="compound_period" value="365">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="compound_period_daily">daily</label>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" id="compound_period_monthly" type="radio" name="compound_period" value="12" checked>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="compound_period_monthly">monthly</label>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" id="compound_period_annually" type="radio" name="compound_period" value="1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="compound_period_annually">annually</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <div>Future Balance</div>
                <div class="h3" id="future_balance">?</div>
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
    (function() {
  var initial_deposit = document.querySelector('#initial_deposit'),
    contribution_amount = document.querySelector('#contribution_amount'),
    investment_timespan = document.querySelector('#investment_timespan'),
    investment_timespan_text = document.querySelector('#investment_timespan_text'),
    estimated_return = document.querySelector('#estimated_return'),
    future_balance = document.querySelector('#future_balance');

  function updateValue(element, action) {
    var min = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('min')),
      max = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('max')),
      step = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('step')) || 1,
      oldValue = element.dataset.value || element.defaultValue || 0,
      newValue = parseFloat(element.value.replace(/$/, ''));

    if (isNaN(parseFloat(newValue))) {
      newValue = oldValue;
    } else {
      if (action == 'add') {
        newValue += step;
      } else if (action == 'sub') {
        newValue -= step;
      }

      newValue = newValue < min ? min : newValue > max ? max : newValue;
    }

    element.dataset.value = newValue;
    element.value = (element.dataset.prepend || '') + newValue + (element.dataset.append || '');

    updateChart();
  }

  function getChartData() {
    var P = parseFloat(initial_deposit.dataset.value), // Principal
      r = parseFloat(estimated_return.dataset.value / 100), // Annual Interest Rate
      c = parseFloat(contribution_amount.dataset.value), // Contribution Amount
      n = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="compound_period"]:checked').value), // Compound Period
      n2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="contribution_period"]:checked').value), // Contribution Period
      t = parseInt(investment_timespan.value), // Investment Time Span
      currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();

    var labels = [];
    for (var year = currentYear; year < currentYear + t; year++) {
      labels.push(year);
    }

    var principal_dataset = {
      label: 'Total Principal',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 123, 255)',
      data: []
    };

    var interest_dataset = {
      label: "Total Interest",
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(23, 162, 184)',
      data: []
    };

    for (var i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
      var principal = P + (c * n2 * i),
        interest = 0,
        balance = principal;

      if (r) {
        var x = Math.pow(1 + r / n, n * i),
          compound_interest = P * x,
          contribution_interest = c * (x - 1) / (r / n2);
        interest = (compound_interest + contribution_interest - principal).toFixed(0)
        balance = (compound_interest + contribution_interest).toFixed(0);
      }

      future_balance.innerHTML = '' +
      balance;
      principal_dataset.data.push(principal);
      interest_dataset.data.push(interest);
    }

    return {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [principal_dataset, interest_dataset]
    }
  }

  function updateChart() {
    var data = getChartData();

    chart.data.labels = data.labels;
    chart.data.datasets[0].data = data.datasets[0].data;
    chart.data.datasets[1].data = data.datasets[1].data;
    chart.update();
  }

  initial_deposit.addEventListener('change', function() {
    updateValue(this);
  });

  contribution_amount.addEventListener('change', function() {
    updateValue(this);
  });

  estimated_return.addEventListener('change', function() {
    updateValue(this);
  });

  investment_timespan.addEventListener('change', function() {
    investment_timespan_text.innerHTML = this.value + ' years';
    updateChart();
  });

  investment_timespan.addEventListener('input', function() {
    investment_timespan_text.innerHTML = this.value + ' years';
  });

  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[name="contribution_period"], [name="compound_period"]');
  for (var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
    radios[j].addEventListener('change', updateChart);
  }
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-counter]');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
     var field = document.querySelector('[name="' + this.dataset.field + '"]'),
       action = this.dataset.counter;

     if (field) {
       updateValue(field, action);
     }
    });
  }

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'),
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: getChartData(),
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: false,
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ':'  +
              tooltipItem.yLabel;
            }
          }
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Year'
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
              callback: function(value) {
                return '' +
                value;
              }
            },
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Balance'
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });

})();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: bro Yar Ajeeb scene ho rha hy ...

Comment: I have copy-pasted all of yours too but still not working

Comment: copy paste the last snippet in a .html file and open file in browser

Comment: YAR BAHI LOVE HO AP HO GYA SET THANK YOU YAR ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥

Comment: Answer accept krna na bhoolna

Comment: doosra answer accept kr gya hai

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Symbols and delimiters on the returns. the errors are commented and the correction given.

```
//  return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': 
//  + tooltipItem.yLabel;

return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ' +    tooltipItem.yLabel;

// future_balance.innerHTML = '
// + balance;

future_balance.innerHTML = '$' + balance;


//  return '
// + value;

return '$' + value;
```